# OpenCV drawMatches error

Tags: c++, opencv

My code consists of a section where I sort through a set of matches and define good matches based on distance. When I try to drawMatches, I receive an error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size())) in drawMatches, file /home/user/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 207
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:207: error: (-215) i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size()) in function drawMatches
```

draw.cpp file shows:

```
// draw matches
for( size_t m = 0; m < matches1to2.size(); m++ )
{
     if( matchesMask.empty() || matchesMask[m] )
     {
          int i1 = matches1to2[m].queryIdx;
          int i2 = matches1to2[m].trainIdx;
          CV_Assert(i1 >= 0 && i1 < static_cast<int>(keypoints1.size()));
          CV_Assert(i2 >= 0 && i2 < static_cast<int>(keypoints2.size()));
          const KeyPoint &kp1 = keypoints1[i1], &kp2 = keypoints2[i2];
          _drawMatch( outImg, outImg1, outImg2, kp1, kp2, matchColor, flags );
     }
}
```

My drawMatches call follows:

```
Mat matchesImage;

drawMatches( im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2,
    good_matches, matchesImage, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

Can anybody help explain this error to me?

**Update:**

Here is my code for the good_matches calculation

```
double min_dist = 10000;
double max_dist = 0;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++ ) { 
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++ ) {
    if( matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.02) ) { 
        good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); 
    }
}

for( int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++ ) {
    printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", 
        i, good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); 
}

cout << "number of good matches: " << (int)good_matches.size() << endl;;

//Draw matches and save file
Mat matchesImage;

drawMatches( im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2,
    good_matches, matchesImage, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

**Update 2:**

```
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

Comment: What function do you use to compute good_matches variable?

Comment: Check out the update to my question.

Comment: I've added my matcher code in Update 2

Comment: does it work if you give 'matches' (instead of 'good_matches') to the drawMatches function?

Comment: Yes it does work if I use 'matches'

Comment: I probably see your bug. Do you know about following relation: descriptors1.rows >= matches.size() ?

Comment: results: descriptors1.rows: 87;
matches.size: 72;

Comment: @MarcinKolny - what did you mean by your last comment?

Comment: What's the type of your descriptor extractor? As well as do you see `-1`s between the elements of `good_matches[i].queryIdx` or `good_matches[i].trainIdx`?

Comment: @P3d0r, note, that your descriptors1.rows can equal e.g. 40, and matches.size() can be e.g. 20 in that case. So in your loop:
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++ ) { 
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
you're trying to access to element e.g. matches[30], which actually doesn't exist. Classic index out of bound error.

Comment: drawMatches( im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2,

should be
drawMatches( im2, keypoints2, im1, keypoints1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, good_matches is an array, which binds points from both *keypoints1* and *keypoints2* array. So point *keypoints1[good_matches[m].queryIdx]* corresponds to point *keypoints2[good_matches[m].trainIdx]*.
As you can see, assertions in opencv code have sense.

It seems, the problem is in  *matches* array.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has to do with the order you matched the points.
If you did, e.g.:

```
match(right_desc, left_desc)
```

function `drawMatches` will have to follow the same order. This will work (considering my matching example):

```
drawMatches(right_rgb, right_pts, left_rgb, left_pts, matches)
```

this will produce the error you have:

```
drawMatches(left_rgb, left_pts, right_rgb, right_pts, matches)
```

The order will also affect what is query and what is train (i.e. `queryIdx` and `trainIdx`), when you access the coordinates of the matches. Note that `right_pts` and `left_pts` are the keypoints described by `right_desc` and `left_desc` respectively.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should clear the contents of the `good_matches` vector with the `good_matches.clear()` command for each iteration (if you use `while(1)` loop for get frame from camera, you will write `good_matches.clear()` command after `while(1)` loop:

```
while(1) {
     good_matches.clear();
     // other code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with answers above.

Parameters you pass into  `matcher.match(dscp1, dscp2, matches)` and `drawMatch(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good_matches)` are corresponding (they are both matching every descriptor in `keypoints1` from `keypoints2`, `keypoints1` is called query set while `keypoints2` is called train set.)

The error might be caused by the wrong `keypoints1` and `keypoints2` you pass into `drawMatch()`. Check whether the index in `good_matches` correspond with kp in `keypoints1`. (If you reduce the number of `keypoints` while picking good matches, this occasion could happen.)