# BFMatcher knnMatch

Tags: c++, opencv, brute-force

I try to implement knnMatch on BFMatcher as follows:

```
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);
vector<DMatch> matches;
//matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 2);
```

And receive the following error:

```
fiducialMain.cpp: In function ‘void fiducialCalc(cv::Mat, cv::Mat, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int&)’:
fiducialMain.cpp:98:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::BFMatcher::knnMatch(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&, int)’
  matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches,2);
                                                        ^
fiducialMain.cpp:98:56: note: candidates are:
In file included from fiducialMain.cpp:15:0:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1116:18: note: void cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >&, int, const cv::Mat&, bool) const
     CV_WRAP void knnMatch( const Mat& queryDescriptors, const Mat& trainDescriptors,
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1116:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘std::vector<cv::DMatch>’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >&’
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1130:18: note: void cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch(const cv::Mat&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >&, int, const std::vector<cv::Mat>&, bool)
     CV_WRAP void knnMatch( const Mat& queryDescriptors, CV_OUT vector<vector<DMatch> >& matches, int k,
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp:1130:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >&’
```

Can anybody explain this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please have another look at [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#void%20DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch(const%20Mat&%20queryDescriptors,%20const%20Mat&%20trainDescriptors,%20vector%3Cvector%3CDMatch%3E%20%3E&%20matches,%20int%20k,%20const%20Mat&%20mask,%20bool%20compactResult)%20const)

while the ordinary match function has a `vector<DMatch>` as result,

knnMatch (say loud : k-nearest-neighbours !) results in several(k) vectors, thus you need a :

vector< vector< DMatch > > matches

for the result

Comment: hey, i guess, that's a *very common* pitfall ! (you're not alone with that)

Comment: Unfortunately, the drawMatches function does not run with vector< vector <DMatch> > since it calls for only a single vector per the docs (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html)

Comment: true, you will have to iterate over that. (or take only the 1st one.) if i may ask: why did you need a knnMatch (not the regular match) ?

Comment: Short answer - I was trying to find the best matches with knnMatch because I was having bug issues with my good_matches algorithm (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725273/opencv-drawmatches-error?noredirect=1#comment45759998_28725273). Maybe not the best approach but I was experimenting

Answer (score 4):

Your arguments for **BFMatcher** are not correct. When you set **crossCheck** as **true**, you can have only one match per keypoint. Whereas, for **knnMatch** you need to have more than one match. So your code should be like:

```
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
std::vector<vector<DMatch> > matches;
matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches,2);

std::vector<DMatch> match1;
std::vector<DMatch> match2;

for(int i=0; i<matches.size(); i++)
{
    match1.push_back(matches[i][0]);
    match2.push_back(matches[i][1]);
}

Mat img_matches1, img_matches2;
drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, match1, img_matches1);
drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, match2, img_matches2);
```